# How can I pass a result of command to another command as a parameter?

Tags: cmd

I should pass a list of files to another command as a parameter

The command that makes file list is like below

```
dir /s/b ..\..\components\*.vue
```

I tried to pass a variable that read the file. But I didn't work. Because the file list is too long(> 8K) to be a parameter of a command. 
Batch file is like below.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Files=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type filelist') do (
    set Files=!Files! %%i
)   
node ..\..\..\node_modules\easygettext\src\extract-cli.js --output messages.pot !Files!
```

Can I pass the dir command to node command?

I used find command on my Mac. But I can't find the solution on Windows.

```
../../node_modules/.bin/gettext-extract --output ../i18n/po/messages.pot $(find ../components -type f -name '*.vue')
```

Comment: What is the reason you have to send all files as a complete string?

Comment: extract-cli.js needs all files list as a parameter. extract-cli.js extracts messages from javascript files. I tried to find another way to pass file list but couldn't find it.

Comment: But there is a line input limitation of 8192 bytes.

Comment: We can pass many file using pipe in a Unix. Is there any way to pass many files like a Unix?

Comment: Or If I use another script (not batch), I can do it? like Powershell, Node, Python, etc...

Comment: Or should I use bash on Windows?